# AVX determine number of written values

Tags: gcc, avx512

I have a 512 bit wide vector register (16 values) and a mask to store them to memory using `_mm512_mask_i32scatter_epi32()`. To determine how many values are written to memory I count the leading zeroes of the mask using `__builtin_clz()`. If the mask is not (!) empty, everything works fine. But when the mask is empty something strange happens:

```
std::cout << "mask = " << mask << " clz(mask) " << __builtin_clz(mask) << "\n";
```

> mask = 0 clz(mask) 31

I have two questions:

1. Does anyone know, why clz is 31 and not 32?
2. Is there a better way to determine the number of written values?

Sincerely

Comment: From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html if the operand is 0, the result is undefined.

Comment: Shouldn't it be rather popcount(~mask)?

Comment: Ahhh! Well! THANKS for the replies! popcount did the trick! :)